# What are obsolete snapshots and snapshot files?

Tags: jestjs

I find the Jest Snapshot Summary a bit confusing. After running tests in one of our repositories, I get the following Summary:

```
Snapshot Summary
 › 2 snapshots written in 1 test suite.
 › 50 obsolete snapshot files found, re-run with `-u` to remove them.
 › 3 obsolete snapshots found, re-run with `-u` to remove them.
```

Snapshot testing means we compare the current tests' output against the output before our changes, to catch side effects.

Hence, if I get it right, the summary means

- 2 tests are new, no snapshots were available to compare against
- 50 tests still provide the same output as before
- 3 tests have been removed, but the snapshots are still around

So running with `-u` would

- Update the time stamp for 50 snapshots, but not change their contents
- Delete the files for 3 snapshots that are useless

Is that understanding correct?

Comment: I ran it with -u and it updated the obsolete status of those tests.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's been a while I posted this question and by know I can answer it myself:

**"Obsolete" refers to snapshots or snapshot files, for which no `.toMatchSnapshot()` exists any more**.

Snapshots are organised in one file per test suite. Single snapshots in those files are stored along with the name of their test, given in jest's `it()` function. If you rename a test, the old snapshot is still in the snapshots file, but recognised as "obsolete".

> `› 2 snapshots written in 1 test suite.`
>
> ⇒ 2 tests are new, no snapshots were available to compare against

This one holds true.

> `› 50 obsolete snapshot files found`
>
> 50 tests still provide the same output as before

Is **wrong**, the 50 corresponding test suites have been renamed, moved or removed. Such a high number is unusual and you should probably find a way to re-map the snapshots to their tests, before updating them.

> `› 3 obsolete snapshots found`
>
> ⇒ 3 tests have been removed, but the snapshots are still around

So this is only partly right, since the tests might have been renamed, not removed.